# Failed to index jar - Unexpected record signature: 0X622F2123

Tags: artifactory

I've upgraded two instances of Artifactory to 6.9.0 version. One of them works without issue(OpenJDK 1.8.131 on centos 7.4), but I see error in the artifactory.log on another instance(OpenJDK version "1.8.0_151" on OEL 6.9):

```
2019-04-11 08:10:49,379 [art-exec-15] [ERROR] (o.a.s.a.ArchiveIndexerImpl:162) - Failed to index 'repository-name:com/service/service/0.14.2.1154/service-0.14.2.1154.jar': Unexpected record signature: 0X622F2123
```

I've tried to switch artifactory to Oracle JDK 1.8.0_121 and OpenJDK 11.0.2 - it didn't help.

p.s. 
REST API and Artifactory GUI return artifacts without any issue. 
The issue isn't reproduced on small jars without dependencies.

Comment: Have you checked after re-indexing?

Comment: We use the repository with the type "maven". It doesn't support "Recalculate Index". We have plenty of uploads from different projects and all of them reports:2019-04-11 08:10:49,379 [art-exec-15] [ERROR] (o.a.s.a.ArchiveIndexerImpl:162) - Failed to index .....jar: Unexpected record signature: 0X622F2123.